# Saving result on Radio Button

Tags: java, android

I made a `xml` with two radio buttons and I want if the user chooses a radio button one or two the result was the saving and restoration on the next start up, can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest storing this information into your SharedPreferences.  Then on start-up, you look for what value is stored and set your radio buttons accordingly.

Take a look at this link for more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref